# fill assetId in local substrate into dex pallet

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I'm trying to create a decentralized exchange (dEX) in Substrate and I have a function called `create_exchange` that has two parameters: `asset_id` and `liquidity_token_id`. I'm having trouble filling the `asset_id` parameter with the desired `AssetIdOf<T>` value in my local Substrate environment. I don't know how can i fill the `assetId`.

**How can I fill assetId in substrate?**

this is my repository [Repo](https://github.com/dortajkianoush/substrate_dex/blob/main/pallets/dex/src/lib.rs)

```
pub fn create_exchange(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            asset_id: AssetIdOf<T>,
            liquidity_token_id: AssetIdOf<T>,
            currency_amount: BalanceOf<T>,
            token_amount: AssetBalanceOf<T>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            // -------------------------- Validation part --------------------------
            let caller = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            ensure!(currency_amount >= T::MinDeposit::get(), Error::<T>::CurrencyAmountTooLow);
            ensure!(token_amount > Zero::zero(), Error::<T>::TokenAmountIsZero);
            if T::Assets::total_issuance(asset_id.clone()).is_zero() {
                Err(Error::<T>::AssetNotFound)?
            }

            if <Exchanges<T>>::contains_key(asset_id.clone()) {
                Err(Error::<T>::ExchangeAlreadyExists)?
            }

            // ----------------------- Create liquidity token ----------------------
            T::AssetRegistry::create(
                liquidity_token_id.clone(),
                T::pallet_account(),
                false,
                <AssetBalanceOf<T>>::one(),
            )
            .map_err(|_| Error::<T>::TokenIdTaken)?;

            // -------------------------- Update storage ---------------------------
            let exchange = Exchange {
                asset_id: asset_id.clone(),
                currency_reserve: <BalanceOf<T>>::zero(),
                token_reserve: <AssetBalanceOf<T>>::zero(),
                liquidity_token_id: liquidity_token_id.clone(),
            };
            let liquidity_minted = T::currency_to_asset(currency_amount);

            Self::do_add_liquidity(
                exchange,
                currency_amount,
                token_amount,
                liquidity_minted,
                caller,
            )?;

            Self::deposit_event(Event::ExchangeCreated(asset_id, liquidity_token_id));
            Ok(())
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to fill it in? In tests? In your browser PolkadotJS? Are there even any assets?

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi i using the contract ui and use the substrate frontend .